# Postgresql query to update fields using a regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have the following data in my "Street_Address_1" column:

> 123 Main Street

Using Postgresql, how would I write a query to update the "Street_Name" column in my Address table?  In other words, "Street_Name" is blank and I'd like to populate it with the street name value contained in the "Street_Address_1" column.

From what I can tell, I would want to use the "regexp_matches" string method.  Unfortunately, I haven't had much luck.

NOTE: You can assume that all addresses are in a "StreetNumber StreetName StreetType" format.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like...:

```
UPDATE table
SET Street_Name = substring(Street_Address_1 FROM '^[0-9]+ ([a-zAZ]+) ')
```

See [relevant section from PGSQL 8.3.7 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), the `substring` form is detailed shortly after the start of the section.

Comment: No luck with that regex.  I'm strugglging with the regex in this case more so than the query.

Comment: More like '^[0-9]+ ([a-zA-Z ]+)'

Comment: That returns the "123 Main" portion of the address.  I strictly want "Main".

Comment: And only the fist occurrence of the text.  I don't care if the street name has two words in it (i.e., 123 Grand Central Avenue).

Comment: This then - '^[0-9]+ (.*) [a-zA-Z ]+$'

Answer (score 28):

If you just want to take Street_Address_1 and strip out any leading numbers, you can do this:

```
UPDATE table
SET street_name = regexp_replace(street_address_1, '^[0-9]* ','','');
```

This takes the value in street_address_1 and replaces any leading string of numbers (plus a single space) with an empty string (the fourth parameter is for optional regex flags like "g" (global) and "i" (case-insensitive)).

This version allows things like "1212 15th Street" to work properly.