# SQL Adding Data Into a Cell That's Already Filled

Tags: sql

I don't know what it would be called to do this, so I don't exactly know how to do a lot of searching for it.

Here's and example database:

```
 name     id     code
 bob      1      Aa Bb cc DD ee
 sue      3      aa Bb Cc Dd Ee
 tom      8      AA BB cc dd EE
```

I want to be able to add an "F" group between the "C" group and "D" group. So it would be:

```
 name     id     code
 bob      1      Aa Bb cc ff DD ee
 sue      3      aa Bb Cc ff Dd Ee
 tom      8      AA BB cc ff dd EE
```

Any idea on how I could get this done?

Comment: Is there a good reason for storing multi-valued attributes, instead of moving them to a [separate table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)?

Comment: Use `SELECT` to copy the text to a variable, then add the "F" group in the string, then use `UPDATE` to add the row back to the table, but I do recommend the above comment. What scripting language are you using with this?

Comment: PHP is going calling the database information to the website. I'll look into the separate table thing, but I don't think it will be a good solution. The above is an example and doesn't directly relate to the actual database other than the fact that I need to insert text in the middle of other text in one of the columns.

Comment: @Chelsea database denormalization can be justified in many circumstances (that's why I also attempted to answer below) - if this is an one-off situation, and you generally only consume the `code` text as a whole, then it's fine to keep it as a single column. But if the groups are important on their own (i.e. they are the atomic data, not the whole string), and you find yourself having to query or update individual groups leaving the rest unchanged, then it might be time to consider normalizing the table (you might not even need a separate table, only separate columns in the same one).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Yes, this is a one time thing and the column is generally called as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update mytable set code = replace(code, "cc DD", "cc ff DD") -- where is optional;
```

and more updates for other variations of capitalization of cc and dd (16 variations in all):

```
update mytable set code = replace(code, "Cc DD", "Cc ff DD") -- where is optional;
update mytable set code = replace(code, "CC DD", "CC ff DD") -- where is optional;
update mytable set code = replace(code, "cC DD", "cC ff DD") -- where is optional;
-- etc
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQLServer 2005+ use [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function

```
SELECT name, id, STUFF(code, 9, 1, ' ff ') AS Code
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standardized way of doing this, but many databases have ways to do regex operations on table columns. In PostgreSQL, for instance, you could do this:

```
UPDATE table
SET code = regex_replace(code, '(.. .. ..) (.. ..)', E'\\1 ff \\2', '');
```

(Note: this code was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975396/520779) and [these docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), but I haven't tested it myself, so there might be errors)

Answer (score 1):

Since your column has fixed length , there is no need of searching for variations of upper and lower case characters. You can get what you required by utilizing character positions .
Use `left()` function to extract first 8 characters and `right()` to extract last 5 characters and sandwich **' ff '** between the two.

Note I have done this on **SQL Server** , equivalent functionality can easily be implemented in other DB

```
UPDATE yourTable
set code = left(code,8)+' ff ' + right(code,5)
```

**Output**

```
Aa Bb cc ff DD ee
aa Bb Cc ff Dd Ee
AA BB cc ff dd EE
```